# How to pass values between processes after using the fork() call?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, race-condition

I need to create a program that program that will start a race between 4 processes to get a number from the user inputs.  The user will enter 4 numbers (1 to 4), the process that receives the first number (1) will be the winner and in the first place, processes afterward will get second, third and fourth place depending on the number they get from the user.

The program will start by using the fork() System call to create 4 processes, each process created is identified by a number from 1 to 4, this number indicates its creation sequence. For example, the first child process created get ID = 1.

After all, processes are created, the processes will start to request a number from the user. Each process will print the number it got from the user and also print its ID number. The parent does not participate in the race and waits for all child process to finish before it exits.

I think I have the basic structure done but I'm not sure how to pass values between the process or if a legitimate race condition is being accomplished. I also can't get the last 3 process to run.

Here is my output:

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAZVn.png)

Here is expected output:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AykF2.png)

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    int p1, p2, num; 

int procNUM = 1, runNum = 1 ;

void game(int p1,int p2);

int main() {
    
     printf("Enter numbers for processes to race for >>>\n");

    p1 = fork();

    p2 = fork();
    
if (p1 > 0 && p2 > 0) { 
       //parent 
       
      
            printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race.\n",getpid(), procNUM);
            procNUM++;
           // fflush(stdout);
           // scanf("%d", &num);
           // printf("%d", &num);
           // printf(I am a processs with);
       
    } 
    
    else if (p1 == 0 && p2 > 0) 
    { 
    //child 1 
    
     printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race.\n",getpid(), procNUM);
     procNUM++;
    // fflush(stdout);
     
    } 
    
    else if (p1 > 0 && p2 == 0) 
    { 
    //child 2 
   
    printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race.\n",getpid(), procNUM);
    procNUM++;
    //fflush(stdout);
    
    
    } 
    
    else { 
       //child 3
       
    printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race.\n",getpid(), procNUM);
    procNUM++;
   // fflush(stdout);
   
       
        
    } 


    game(p1, p2);

 return 0;   
}


void game(int p1,int p2){
    if (p1 > 0 && p2 > 0) { 
       //parent 
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race and I am in %d place.\n",getpid(), procNUM, runNum);
            //fflush(stdout);
            runNum++;
       
    } 
    
    else if (p1 == 0 && p2 > 0) 
    { 
    //child 1 
    
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race and I am in %d place.\n",getpid(), procNUM, runNum);
            //fflush(stdout);
       runNum++;
    
    
    } 
    
    else if (p1 > 0 && p2 == 0) 
    { 
    //child 2 
   
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race and I am in %d place.\n",getpid(), procNUM, runNum);
           // fflush(stdout);
       runNum++;
    
    } 
    
    else { 
       //child 3
       
            scanf("%d", &num);
            printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race and I am in %d place.\n",getpid(), procNUM, runNum);
            //fflush(stdout);
       runNum++;
        
    } 
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After `fork`'ing, your procNUM variable "branches" and has nothing in common with the parent's procNUM, so incrementing it will not tell anything to the parent process (copy on write).

To pass a value to child process use the argv[] array - it is an argument to `execvp` function.

I suggest going the standard way: in master program start a number of threads, each of these threads starts a child process. The child process (game.c) code is simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    return num;
}
```

The parent program is a bit more involved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
// #include <threads.h>
// #include <stdatomic.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Compile the program above to  'game' using "gcc -o game game.c"
#define N (4)
const char* game_file = "./game";

// Declare PID array, ret_code and threads
int pids[N];
int ret_code[N];
pthread_t thread[N];
// C11: thrd_t thread[N];

// Each thread increments this atomic int when the child process finishes
/* C11: atomic_int */ int proc_finish_count;
```

The thread procedure is

```
int game_proc(void *arg) {
    int i = *((int*)arg);
    pids[i] = fork();
    if (pids[i] > 0) {
        while(1) {
            int st;
            int res = waitpid(pids[i], &st, WNOHANG);
            if (res == pids[i]) {
                proc_finish_count++;
                // In C11 use atomics :
                // atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&proc_finish_count, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
                printf(" I am a process with pid %d and I am process number %d in the race and I am in %d place.\n", pids[i], i, proc_finish_count);
                break;
            } else
            if (res < -1) {
                // error while waiting
                return 1;
            }
        }
    } else { 
        // Here you can pass parameters to `game` - insert the list of strings before NULL
        execlp(game_file, game_file, NULL);
        printf("Error running process\n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

And the main function simply starts and wait for the threads

```
int main(){
    int i;
    proc_finish_count = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
        ret_code[i] = i; // index of the process
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &game_proc, &ret_code[i]);
        // C11: thrd_create(&thread[i], &game_proc, &ret_code[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        pthread_join(&thread[i], NULL);
        // C11: thrd_join(thread[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Since your child processes "compete" for standard input, I would  suggest starting something like "xterm" or other terminal emulator as a child process - this way the inputs can "compete" for real.

Comment: While compiling this, I am getting an error saying threads.h not found. This is the command gcc -o parent Dee_parent.c. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: I am using C11 standard, if you have an older compiler change thrd_create to pthread_create and thrd_join to pthread_join. Also, the thrd_t is now pthread_t and parameters to pthread_create should have another NULL (see man page).

Comment: Since you are using GCC, just try the "gcc -std=c11 -o parent parent.c" command (enable C11 support explicitly)

Comment: I think, no modifications are necessary. I did not want to use C11 in the first place, but the code with OS-specific atomics and libpthread appeared to be more verbose.

Comment: I tried running it with C18 and it gave me the same threads.h not found error. It wants the pthread,h file and that requires you to change all of the  regular thread functions to pthread functions. I cant figure out how to get it to work with the pthreads.

Comment: There's nothing to figure out: change atomic_int to int, change thrd_create to pthread_create, thrd_join to pthread_join, thrd_t to pthread_t and remove atomic_increment. I've already mentioned this in a reply to Abshishek's question. In case you are still having troubles reading man pages for pthread_create, I have changed the source code above.